# Python Script to Delete All Lines except for "good words"

Tags: python

I have the opposite script that works great, but need a script that will delete all lines except for the lines that have the "good words"  It would be the opposite of this script that works great for bad words.  Any help is appreciated.

```
bad_words = ['abc:', 'xyz:']  
with open('poop.txt') as badfile, open('Clean.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
    for line in badfile:
      clean = True
    for word in bad_words:
        if word in line:
            clean = False
    if clean == True:
        cleanfile.write(line)
```

Comment: yo, just swap your clean boolean value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent another if with the for statement and invert last if

```
bad_words = ['abc:', 'xyz:']  
with open('poop.txt') as badfile, open('Clean.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
    for line in badfile:
      clean = True
      for word in bad_words:
          if word in line:
              clean = False
      if not clean == True:
          cleanfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to write only bad words, you need to invert the condition that determines whether you write or not. As in change the `True` into `False`

```
bad_words = ['abc:', 'xyz:']  
with open('poop.txt') as badfile, open('Clean.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
    for line in badfile:
      clean = True
      for word in bad_words:
          if word in line:
              clean = False
      if clean == False:
          cleanfile.write(line)
```

This can also be expressed by using the `not` operator. So you could write `if not clean:`